# Result processing in stored procedure SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that looks like:

```
        AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result nvarchar(max)
    SELECT @result = COALESCE(@result + ', ', '') + ingredient.NAME
      FROM MEAL
 LEFT JOIN MEAL meal ON MEAL.ID= ingredient.MEAL_ID
      JOIN INGREDIENT ingredient ON ingredient.INGREDIENT_ID = problem_type.GID
     where MEAL.ID=@ID
RETURN @result
END
```

The meal can contain ingredients(flour,meat etc.). Lets say that I don't check ingredients(problem is complex,this is example) and that meal can contain as ingredients flour,flour(2X) and meat. 
When I want to display result in app, this stored procedure will return "Flour, flour, meat" string. I don't won't that, I want "Flour, meat".

How can I do it in stored procedure? 
Is there any way to add some if statement in SELECT(?). In C# for example I can split string and than to check is there any duplicates, but is that possible in stored procedures?

Comment: Use nested select .. basically do SELECT @result = COALESCE(@result + ', ', '') + NAME from ( select distinct ingredient.NAME ....), so you wanna get distinct first and then go with coalesce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use a subquery to get the distinct values and then concatenate them in the outer query:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result nvarchar(max);

    SELECT @result = COALESCE(@result + ', ', '') + i.NAME
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT i.NAME
          FROM INGREDIENT i
          WHERE i.MEAL_ID = @ID
         ) i
    RETURN @result
END
```

Note:  I removed both `JOIN`s in the query.  You have the `MEAL` table twice, which I think is a mistake -- the `ON` conditions are doomed to failure and `problem_type` is not defined.  More importantly, they are not needed because `INGREDIENT` has the `MEAL_ID` for the `WHERE` clause.

Also, without the additional `JOIN`s, you might find that the `DISTINCT` isn't necessary.